# Vue: How do you bind a value to an input through a wrapper component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I know you can use `v-model` to bind a value to an input in the same component. How do you create a wrapper component for an input and bind a value to it?

Login.vue

```html
<template>
  <div id="Login">
    <Input v-bind:value="email"/>    
    <Input v-bind:value="password"/>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Input from './Input.vue'
  import Button from './Button'

  export default {
    name: 'Login',
    components: {
        Input,
        Button,
    },
    data: () => ({
        email:'test',
        password:'test',
    }),
    methods: {
        login: () => { debugger; }, //this.email and this.password are still set to test
    }
  }
</script>
```

Input.vue

```html
<template>
  <div class="input>
   <input v-model="value"/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Input',
    props: {
        value: String,
    },
  }
</script>
```

Current set up results in

`[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "value"`

Is the only way to do this by emitting an event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is use v-model for wrapper and on/emit for input

```
<div id="Login">
    <Input v-model="email"/>    
    <Input v-model="password"/>    
</div>
```

...

```
<div class="input>       
   <input        
     v-bind:value="value"
     v-on:input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
   >
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I got it correctly, you can try to create **transparent** wrapper (in my case AppInput)

SomeParent.vue

```html
<div>
  <AppInput v-model="parentModel" />
</div>
```

AppInput.vue

```html
<template>
  <input
    class="app-input"
    v-bind="$attrs"
    :value="value"
    v-on="{
      ...$listeners,
      input: event => $emit('input', event.target.value)
    }">
</template>
```

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: "AppInput",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  props: ["value"]
};
</script>
```

[one of articles](https://zendev.com/2018/05/31/transparent-wrapper-components-in-vue.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `v-model` directly in the `input` component by doing so.

```html
<template>
  <div class="input>
   <input :value="value" @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    name: 'Input',
    props: ["value"]
  }
</script>
```

And then use it in your parent component like this:

```html
<template>
  <div id="Login">
    <Input v-model="email"/>    
    <Input v-model="password"/>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Input from './Input.vue'
  import Button from './Button'

  export default {
    name: 'Login',
    components: {
        Input,
        Button,
    },
    data: () => ({
        email:'test',
        password:'test',
    }),
    methods: {
        login: () => { debugger; }, //this.email and this.password are still set to test
    }
  }
</script>
```

[See here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)